# How to upload a file to the database using playframework in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

What is the recommended way of handling file uploads to the database using Play!2 with Scala?

Comment: Just a remark: in my experiences it is usually not a good idea to store files in databases directly. It is usually more efficient to store them in the file system, and to store a reference (the path) in the database.

Comment: Does storing files in the file system scale well?

Comment: Well, that's what file systems are good at. Depending on your scenario (many small or a few large files, lots of reads or writes, lots of creates and/or deletes, ...) certain file systems might be better than others, but that is a completely different question and not related to databases.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson You can use distributed locations for storing files, so I think that it _can_ be scalable enough. As **mhs** wrote in most cases storing files in DB is just more expensive than FS, especially  when they are quite large. When DB with files inside grows creating backups becomes more and more terrible. Also DB operations slows down.

Comment: This is right, storing in DB is not a good idea. Play1 provided a simple way to "store file in DB" but in fact only file paths were stored, the file itself was in a directory. I can't see any similar mechanic in play2 anorm package.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific requirements, MongoDB's GridFS will store files for you in a much more efficient and scalable manner than any relational database and filesystem.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS

There are plenty of MongoDB plugins for Play that support GridFS.