# How to serve uploaded files in Play!2 using Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to allow users to upload photos to the server and then view them. Uploading happens as described [in this guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaFileUpload). Here is the code:

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
  request.body.file("picture").map { picture =>
    import java.io.File
    val filename = picture.filename 
    val contentType = picture.contentType
    picture.ref.moveTo(new File("/tmp/picture"))
    Ok("File uploaded")
  }.getOrElse {
    Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
      "error" -> "Missing file"
    )
  }
}
```

It is unclear to me how to serve the uploaded images back to users that want to see them. Right now I am hosting the server on my own machine, so the code snippet from the guide writes the files to my D: drive, which isn't (and shouldn't be) available from the Internet. As far as I can see there are 2 options:

1. Store the photos under the /public folder in my project (the one that is dedicated to assets). See here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Assets
2. Write my own controller that servs images form custom locations from my drive.

For 1, I'm not sure if that is the purpose of assets.
For 2, I have no idea how to write such a controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>2.0.3 will feature an [external Assets controller](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/7a27edadbcc2bf6f009f95e44381624e27bd27db) which might be (mis)used for this. Writing such a controller is no magic though, you have predefined folder where all your uploads are saved, and that's where you read them from. In the database you save the (unique) file name.</strike>

A different approach would be to save the uploaded files in the database. We do this with [GridFS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) in MongoDB. A custom controller serves them back to the user. This way your data is stored in one central place, which also makes backups and recoveries simpler.

Comment: Interesting. It was my understanding however, that storing files right into the database might be bad practice, following this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416735/how-to-upload-a-file-to-the-database-using-playframework-in-scala

Comment: As always, it depends. GridFS is explicitly made for this kind of problem, as is Amazon S3. If you store your files in the local file system, you have a big problem when you need a second server one day. Take a look at the Assets controller, is not that hard to understand.

Comment: You can also use a NAS to share storage between servers and mount it in the right places. You can also upload your files to a CDN and let it serve your files. Going with MongoDB just for file storage is not the better choice I think.

Comment: Yeah that's not what I meant :) We use MongoDB, so GridFS seemed to be the natural choice. Works well so far.

Comment: Using the ExternalAssets controller is only recommended when in Development, this controller is disabled when in Prod mode, for simplicity @jozic's answer would be preferred, with the addition of setting inline = true if you know (and want) the file to be displayed by the browser.

Comment: The external assets part is outdated. You know back in the days we had nothing... ;)

Answer (score 18):

The simple example is

```
def index = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File("/tmp/fileToServe.pdf"))
}
```

there is "Serving files" section at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaStream#Serving-files which explains how to serve files

Comment: I would favour this solution rather than the ExternalAssets controller since it's disabled in Development mode.

Comment: The question was not about how to serve files, but how to serve **uploaded** files, and if you can upload to your assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new route like this:

```
GET     /myFiles/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/tmp", file)
```

Comment: I don't expect this to work: "During the build process, the contents of the public folder are processed and added to the application classpath."

Comment: The contents of the PUBLIC folder... Read the rest of the documentation. It should work properly. -> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Assets