# Play Framework 2: Create images in public/images

Tags: java, scala, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have created an application to generate barcode images which store the images in public/images/barcode using the following code

```
String dir = Play.application().getFile("public/images/barcode").getAbsolutePath();
String barcode = "46062161";
BarcodePrinter.print(barcode,dir + "/"+barcode+".png"); 

public class BarcodePrinter{ 
  private static void Save_image(Image image,String filePath)
  {
    try 
    {
      BufferedImage bi = (BufferedImage) image;
      File outputfile = new File(filePath);
      ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
      Logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

and in my view file

```
@imgpath(barcode:String) = @{
"/assets/images/barcode/"+barcode+".png"
}
<img src="@imgpath(barcode)" />
```

this code work only on development and it does not work in heroku. I got this error from logs

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/target/../public/images/barcode/46062161.png (No such file or directory)
```

please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: how are you writing/saving the .png files? Sometimes I store temporary data (like temporary .xls files) in heroku and it works for me.

Comment: also, try to access your file using the Assets routing: @routes.Assets.at("images/barcode/<filename-here>")

Comment: @wleao I have edited my code. can you show me how did you store temporary data in heroku? I have tried routes.Assets.at and it works on development not in heroku. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to write to the file system on heroku anyway. Here is the relevant part of the documentation:

> Ephemeral filesystem
>
> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the
>   most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running
>   processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no
>   files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and
>   any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or
>   restarted.

The best solution would probably be a cloud storage service like S3.

Comment: or store the files in a database (not the best solution at all...)

Answer (score 1):

Play packages all files when you call dist before putting it into production mode, this means the router doesn't find files created after this. I haven't tried 2.1 where this may have been fixed, I remember seeing something about this on the mailing list. I think you want to use the ExternalAssets class.

Comment: I have tried to create a new controller like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688567/handling-dynamic-created-files-in-play-2 but it also does not work

Comment: What's the error? Are you sure the local path is correct (check with the debugger)?

Comment: the error is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/public/images/barcode/27462759.png (No such file or directory)

Comment: Do you actually keep your app at the root directory?