# Playframework 2.2 : Uploaded Files in Public directory not accessible

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am having problems with accessing file in public directory after deployment. 
The `stage` command give me a folder `target\universal\bin` where my `.exe` file is. 
In development mode I used to upload my files to `public\uploads\pictures` and access them from this location. But, after deployment I am unable to upload the pictures. I read this [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451246/how-to-serve-uploaded-files-in-play2-using-scala) that has two options. Is  it possible to define a folder directory that is not absolute.

**Application Conf**

```
myUploadPath="public/Upload/Pictures/"
```

**Accessing folder**

```
   String myUploadPath = Play.application().configuration()
                        .getString(myUploadPath);
```

Please tell me a solution to overcome this..

Comment: Do you get some sort of error message? Anything?

Comment: @Carsten Nope the if the files are not uploaded than I have handled the exception. And the exception handling is done. but, I have found a solution .. Please check my update.

Answer (score 1):

**Found a solution**

During development we are using public directory to store anything extras(in my case uploaded files) that we have. But, while deploying the application it is important that we change the reference to these extra files. I have changed the path from public directory to the absolute path of where the file is executed using

`Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath()`

and store the files in this directory.

If you don't want to use this than you can also specify an [External Asset](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.5/api/scala/controllers/ExternalAssets%24.html)